# I just need someone to help me with a tiny actionscript error

Tags: actionscript-3

I've made the hourly wages calculator, but there is one problem:
I can't get it to calculate anything, so if you were to use this program;
you would add your name, hours worked and wages. once you click the button, at the bottom with
have your results.

i'm trying to get it to say hi, "the person's name" you have this much... something like that.

can anyone help me?

thanks

here is my code:

```
button.mouseChildren = false
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick); 
}


private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.results.text = "Hi, "
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You code has some issues, have you tried this?

```
button.mouseChildren = false;
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   this.results.text = "Hi, ";
}
```

Some things to remember:

```
// + End lines with ;
// + Start new code on their own line
// + Don't comment out your onClick function
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: i ended up getting my text box working and showing anyone's name, but any examples in how to get my hours worked and wages to show the results. i have it so i would put my name, the hours i worked (for the day) say 8, then how much i get an hour(wages) say $9. how do i get it to calculate those and have the this.results.text show those results too